# HATS !!!!! GET SPECIAL HATS ON 21 DEC, 25 DEC, AND 1 JAN!

Tags: discussion, participation, community, winter-bash

Participation tends to drop badly as we enter the Christmas and New Year period, just as it may have [dropped in November due to Diwali](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/218/5).

For a small and new site like ours, we might not be able to afford several days without any activity, as our most enthusiastic users may get tired of signing in each day only to find no new questions to answer or even read, which could cause a lot of people to lose interest, and eventually lead to the death of this community we have built (this happened on the [Homebrewing Stack Exchange](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/q/486/18390) and the [Vegetarian Stack Exchange](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/), each which have only 0.1 questions/day now, meaning that the communities are pretty much dead).

Every year [since 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161189/391772), hats have been issued to users who participate during the holiday season at around the time of Christmas and the New Year, which has had quite a lot of success in keeping participation fun during the holiday seasons (and already we've seen a lot of new users come to join Matter Modeling SE to earn their [gimme space](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/gimme-space) hat).

There's some very easy hats you can get on certain days:

- [Where in the world](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/where-in-the-world-moon) (ask, answer, or upvote a question or answer on 21 December)
- [bûche-de-noël](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/b%C3%BBche-de-no%C3%ABl) (ask, answer, or upvote a question or answer on 25 December)
- [Happy new year](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/happy-new-year) (Post a message in chat on 1 January 2021, that gets starred by someone)

There's plenty of other fun that you can have, in many different ways, during hat season. Just look around and you'll see plenty of fun things to do. For example you might like to [show off your hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358505/391772) or to support fellow Matter Modelers that have shown off theirs! Here's some examples from our community:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Note: the date for these hats is determined based on UTC (+-12 hrs from 00:00 UTC for that date). For example, I just earned the bûche-de-noël from voting at 10am my time, but 4pm UTC on the 24th.

Comment: I think we can unfeature this now :P